# When window is split on startup, how to open the file on the right side?

Tags: emacs, window, startup

How do I open a file foo, associated with a major mode (in this case python, so it's a foo.py), on the right side of a split window (and the window is split only for this major mode)? The following code doesn't work at all (it displays the *scratch* buffer on both sides).

```
(defun my-eval-after-load-python()
  (split-window-horizontally)
)
(eval-after-load "python" '(my-eval-after-load-python))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting up a particular `major-mode` that matches a file name or file extension, see the variable `auto-mode-alist`.  Emacs 25 supports `python-mode` for `.py` file extensions out-of-the-box.

**Caveat re Startup**:  The built-in (hard-coded) library `startup.el` contains some selection of buffers/windows that are displayed on startup.  Customizing a particular window layout upon starting Emacs is always somewhat of a challenge, and the method will most likely be custom to a particular user.  For better results, the user may wish to place the window organization functions at the very bottom of the `.emacs` or `init.el` or use the `emacs-startup-hook` (which runs towards the end of the startup process).  Certain libraries such as `desktop.el` (desktop restore) will complicate the selection of which buffer should have focus when startup finishes.  Each user will need to invest some time organizing the startup in a way that suits his/her needs.  For example, there may be two windows and the user may want to have focus in the other -- something lo-tech like `(other-window 1)` at the bottom of the customization file might be all that is needed.  In the example below with `my-display-buffer`, the value returned is a window -- the user may wish to wrap the last line `window` like this `(select-window window)` so that it gets selected; or, instead of modifying `my-display-buffer`, the user could add `(select-window (my-display-buffer BUFFER ALIST DIRECTION))` when using the function without modifying it internally.  The original poster may also be interested in using `find-file` (to target the current window), or `find-file-other-window` (to create/target another window) -- e.g., `(find-file-other-window "~/foo.py")`.

If focus is already in the desired window (e.g., the window on the right is already selected), then just use something like `set-window-buffer` or `switch-to-buffer`.

To control display of a buffer above, below, left or right, see the following example that uses a custom function called `my-display-buffer` hereinbelow:

**Sample Usage**:  The function definition of `my-display-buffer` would need to appear in the `.emacs` or `init.el` file *prior to* using any of these four sample snippets.

```lisp
(let ((buffer (find-file-noselect "~/foo.py")))
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (message "major-mode:  %s" major-mode))
  (my-display-buffer buffer nil 'left))
```

**or**

```lisp
(let ((buffer (find-file-noselect "~/foo.py")))
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (message "major-mode:  %s" major-mode))
  (my-display-buffer buffer nil 'right))
```

**or**

```lisp
(let ((buffer (find-file-noselect "~/foo.py")))
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (message "major-mode:  %s" major-mode))
  (my-display-buffer buffer nil 'above))
```

**or**

```lisp
(let ((buffer (find-file-noselect "~/foo.py")))
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (message "major-mode:  %s" major-mode))
  (my-display-buffer buffer nil 'below))
```

**Example Function**:

```lisp
(defun my-display-buffer (buffer alist direction &optional size pixelwise)
"BUFFER:  The buffer that will be displayed.
ALIST:  See the doc-string of `display-buffer' for more information.
DIRECTION:  Must use one of these symbols:  'left 'right 'below 'above
SIZE:  See the doc-string for `split-window'.
PIXELWISE:  See the doc-string for `split-window'.
There are three possibilities:
-  (1) If a window on the frame already displays the target buffer,
then just reuse the same window.
-  (2) If there is already a window in the specified direction in relation
to the selected window, then display the target buffer in said window.
-  (3) If there is no window in the specified direction, then create one
in that direction and display the target buffer in said window."
  (let ((window
          (cond
            ((get-buffer-window buffer (selected-frame)))
            ((window-in-direction direction))
            (t
              (split-window (selected-window) size direction pixelwise)))))
    (window--display-buffer buffer window 'window alist display-buffer-mark-dedicated)
    window))
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems it works perfectly. I want the focus on the newly created window, so the select-window idea will be used. There's just one thing I wasn't clear about. The file is opened/created originally from a terminal, like: emacs foo.py, so its name is not stated explicitly in the code (the .emacs), how is that done?

Comment: The following example assumes `my-display-buffer` is somewhere inside the `.emacs` file and the following command line is called from a terminal:  `emacs -nw --eval="(let ((buffer (find-file-noselect \"~/foo.py\"))) (my-display-buffer buffer nil 'right))"`  If I were going to be doing a lot of these, I would set up function inside the `.emacs` file to simply matters.

Comment: Great, it works as expected! It will be done a lot, how would that function be defined? Some function inside the defun would read the name given by the shell? I thought I'd be able to simply type "emacs file.py", I hope it's possible ;(  (Also, I'm curious about the reason you set up the terminal mode -nw)

Comment: The version of Emacs that I use is both the GUI version and the terminal version (combined into one); and, the `-nw` is what tells Emacs to not launch the GUI version -- i.e., without using `-nw`, the GUI version is launched.  Off the top of my head, I do not know how to simplify the example to `emacs file.py` from the terminal.  I could simplify it to `emacs -nw --eval="(my-func \"foo.py\")"` but that's as far as I could go based on my current level of Emacs-fu.

Comment: It seems that simply `(my-display-buffer (current-buffer) alist direction)` inside my eval function does the trick.

Comment: The file to study is `startup.el` -- e.g., the incoming command-line arguments are recorded/set to the variable `command-line-args` and the `.emacs` that loads can access those arguments.  There are so many variations/possibilities in terms of command line arguments, and so many endless possibilities of what a user may have inside his/her user-configuration files, it is difficult/impossible to come up with a guaranteed solution that will work in all cases.  In the end, whatever you decide upon will likely be unique to your own setup.